# Multiple criteria in 1 query

Tags: mysql

I have one table of peoples names and I have another table of pledges these people have made.

They might pledge money against item 1,2,3 or 4.

Each time a pledge is made an entry is made in the pledge table with the id of the person and the pledge number they made.

I would like a query that gets a count of distinct people that made pledges for both 1 and 2 for example.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer. Adriaan

Answer (score 1):

You could try this using the [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT PersonID) DistinctCountPersons
FROM       pledges p
WHERE     EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pledges WHERE PersonID = p.PersonID AND ItemID = 1)
AND     EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pledges WHERE PersonID = p.PersonID AND ItemID = 2)
```

**EDIT**

**Regarding the second part of the query, you can try**

```
SELECT  p.PersonID,
        pp.PersonName,
        SUM(p.Pledge) TotalPledged
FROM    pledges p INNER JOIN
        people pp ON p.PersonID = pp.PersonID
WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pledges WHERE PersonID = p.PersonID AND ItemID = 1)
AND     EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pledges WHERE PersonID = p.PersonID AND ItemID = 2)
GROUP BY p.PersonID,pp.PersonName
```

Comment: That's fantastic, and quick!! Seems to do exactly what I need, although I'm not entirely sure I understand how it is working. My sql knowledge is a little basic! Thanks anyway

Comment: Can I pick your brain a little further please. We have this part working now which is a big help, but now the query needs to go a bit further.

There is another table that contains the person's name linked by the personID column. We would now like to get a list of names of people that match the two criteria and also how much they had pledged as a total (this is contained in the pledges table and they may make multiple pledges for the same item).

Many thanks

Dave

Comment: I have updated the answer, have a look, and let me know if this helps, or if yuo require any further help. astander.

Comment: Only a pleasure. Glad I could help X-)